# Listening to zlib compressed data on server side in JS

Tags: javascript, zlib

So, I compressed a string using zlib in c++ and sent it to server using CURL. I have to read the data in Javascript.
 The data somehow appears in the key, so I use the following code to decompress it:

```js
function submitStats(req, res) {
    console.log("submitted stats");
    req.params=_.extend(req.params || {}, req.query || {}, req.body || {});
    // Params
    // p -> counter
    // u -> user
    // t -> time
    // o -> open
    var statsPath = (req.params.nv) ? STATS_PATH_2 : STATS_PATH_1;
    console.log(req.params);
    var x = req.params;
     for (var key in x )
    {
        if(x.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        console.log(key);
        var buffer = new Buffer(key, 'base64');
        zlib.unzip(buffer, function(err, buffer) {
             if (!err) {
             console.log(buffer.toString());
               }
         });
    }
}
    res.send(200, {"success": true});
}
```

The last console.log doesn't show anything and temp[0] shows undefined. The other logs seem like a compressed string though.

Any ideas on why it isn't working?

Comment: where does `data` and `pako` come from? where does `uncomData` go?

Comment: pako is a zlib port.

Comment: does the built-in node zlib not work?

Comment: please have a llook at the new edits

Comment: what do you mean by built in node zlib?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Comment: wow. i wasted hours on this. will see if it works. thanks

Comment: a good programmer should be "wasting" about half their time. when they don't waste it, they tend to ship stuff that wastes users time instead...

Comment: no, temp[0] shows undefined. that's primarilly a problem now

Comment: Rightly said, I have a great deal more to learn.

Comment: @dandavis even after the changes in edit, it does not show buffer